# Как вывести название категории средней наибольшей значении?

Tags: java, ооп, коллекции, map

Есть задача которую не могу выполнить.
Это ООП с использованием коллекцией Map.
Есть в поле такие значение как: `Category`, `Name`, `Price`.

> Входные данные:

```
Product p1 = new Product("Vehicle", "Kia_Rio", 5_000_000);
        Product p2 = new Product("Smartphone", "Iphone 11", 300_000);
        Product p3 = new Product("Smartphone", "Iphone_11_Pro", 340_000);
        Product p4 = new Product("Smartphone", "Iphone_12", 400_000);
        Product p5 = new Product("Vehicle", "Toyota_Prius", 3_750_000);
        Product p6 = new Product("Laptop", "MacBook_Pro", 650_00000);
        Product p7 = new Product("Shoes", "Crocks", 25_0000000);
        Product p8 = new Product("Shoes", "Nike", 35_0000000);
```

> P.S. Вот среднее значение каждой категории:

```
Vehicle = 4375000
Laptop = 65000000
Shoes = 300000000
Smartphone = 346666
```

> Задача:
> Вывести название категории средней наибольшей значении.

> Мой неполный код:

```
Set<Map.Entry<String, List<Product>>> entries = categoryConsist.entrySet();
        int total = 0;
        String name = "";
        for (Map.Entry<String, List<Product>> entry : entries) {
            int nums = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < entry.getValue().size(); i++) {
                nums += entry.getValue().get(i).getPrice();
            }
            nums /= entry.getValue().size();
            if (nums >= total) {
                total = nums;

            }
        }
        System.out.println("->" + total);
    }
}
```

> В целом выводит корректные цифры, то что нужно. Но задача состоит в том что нужно вывести `Category`. Для этого нужно использовать `String` но что именно записать- не знаю. Должно выйти `Shoes`.

Answer (score 0):

с stream-api довольно красиво получается

```java
List<Product> products = List.of(p1, p2, ... , p8);
Map<String, Double> collect = products.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                Product::getCategory,
                Collectors.averagingInt(Product::getPrice)
        ));
```

Answer (score 0):

Просто при обнаружении очередного максимума обновляйте значение `name`.  Также следует заметить, что при нестрогом условии `if (nums >= total)` будет запоминаться *последняя* категория:

```java
Set<Map.Entry<String, List<Product>>> entries = categoryConsist.entrySet();
String
int maxAvg = 0;
String maxCat = null;
for (Map.Entry<String, List<Product>> e : entries) {
    int total = 0;
    for (Product p : e.getValue()) {
        total += p.getPrice();
    }
    int avg = total / p.getValue().size();
    if (avg > maxAvg) {
        maxAvg = avg;
        maxCat = e.getValue();
    }
}
System.out.println(maxCat + " -> " + maxAvg);
```

---

Или же с использованием Stream API:

- вычислить средние значения цен для каждого списка товаров по категории
- найти максимум

```java
Map.Entry<String, Integer> max = categoryConsist.entrySet()
    .stream() // Stream<Map.Entry<String, List<Product>>>
    .map(e -> Map.entry(
        e.getKey(),
        e.getValue().stream().mapToInt(Product::getPrice).sum()
            / e.getValue().size()
    )) // Stream<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>
    .collect(Collectors.maxBy(Map.Entry.comparingByValue())) // Optional
    .orElse(null);

System.out.println(max.getKey() + " -> " + max.getValue());
```

Также средние значения можно вычислить, используя `IntStream::average`:

```java
// ...
.map(e -> Map.entry(
        e.getKey(),
        (int) e.getValue().stream().mapToInt(Product::getPrice).average().orElse(0.0)
    )) // Stream<Map.Entry<String, Integer>>
// ...
```

Comment: Хотел бы отметить про 1 решение, именно временно он мне и нужен, в этом случае, выходит ошибка, пишет: Required type: String../.Provided: List <Product_Map.Product>

Как бы можно решить в данном случае? Спасибо!